# Matching the entire input with Regex, Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, regex

I have an application that communicates with a serial port. I am looking to create a packet descriptor with regex that can recognize the expression.

The string is `!$S0, 0, 48, 3`and I want the regex to recognize any digit.

```
- (IBAction)getStatus:(id)sender
{
    NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[(!$S\\d,\\s\\d,\\s\\d,\\s\\d)]" options:0 error:0];
    self.getStatus = [[ORSSerialPacketDescriptor alloc] initWithRegularExpression:regex maximumPacketLength:20 userInfo:nil];
    [self.serialPort startListeningForPacketsMatchingDescriptor:self.getStatus];
    NSString *command = @"$S";
    command = [command stringByAppendingString:[self lineEndingString]];
    NSData *dataToSend = [command dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [self.serialPort sendData:dataToSend];
}
```

I expect it to pull the whole response so that I can process the string here:

```
- (void)serialPort:(ORSSerialPort *)serialPort didReceivePacket:(NSData *)packetData matchingDescriptor:(ORSSerialPacketDescriptor *)descriptor {
    NSString *asciString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:packetData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"package[asci]: %@", asciString);

    if (descriptor == self.getStatus) {

   }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is not quite clear, try [`@"!\\$S\\d+,\\s+\\d+,\\s+\\d+,\\s+\\d+"`](https://regex101.com/r/2tdTub/1). Enclose with `^` and `$` if you plan to match the string exactly.

Comment: Yes, that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
@"!\\$S\\d+(?:,\\s+\\d+){3}"
```

Enclose with `^` (start of string) and `$` (end of string) if you plan to match the string exactly:

```
@"^!\\$S\\d+(?:,\\s+\\d+){3}$"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2tdTub/2)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `!`  - a `!`
- `\\$` - a `$` symbol (must be escaped)
- `S` - an `S` letter
- `\\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `(?:,\\s+\\d+){3}` - 3 consecutive sequences of:

  - `,` - a comma
  - `\\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
  - `\\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thank you so much for detailing that! :)